# display:inline-block with border?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        body { margin:0;padding:0;}
        </style>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <div>
        <div style="width:1000px;margin:0 auto;">
            <div style="width:700px;display:inline-block;">1</div>
            <div style="width:300px;display:inline-block;">2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want these blocks flush, but currently the second block is pushed down..
If I change the width of second block to 296px then it works..

I don't want to use `float:left` because it will require one more block with `clear:both;`.

Comment: Add a clearfix class to the wrapping div: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/p5T7W/) is what you have at the moment, but reduced in size:

> I don't want to use float:left because
>   it requires one more block with
>   "clear:both;".

With `float: left`, you can clear/contain the `float`s without adding an element with `clear: both`. You can do this by adding `overflow: hidden` (or [clearfix](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/)) on the parent element.

- [Without `overflow: hidden`](http://jsfiddle.net/p5T7W/1/)
- [With `overflow: hidden`](http://jsfiddle.net/p5T7W/2/)

If you want to stick with `display: inline-block`..

The first thing you need to do is remove the whitespace between the two `divs`.

- [With whitespace](http://jsfiddle.net/p5T7W/)
- [Without whitespace](http://jsfiddle.net/p5T7W/3/)

If you want to add a `border`, you can [add wrapper elements and add the `border`s to that](http://jsfiddle.net/p5T7W/4/).

Or, you can use [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing) as [shown here](http://jsfiddle.net/p5T7W/5/).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use 2 elements in line (1000px total for 300+700px) - just set font-size:0 for container. This is very logical in this case and now you can use all benefits from inline-blocks, like align:justify!

Answer (score 1):

You can only give display:inline-block to elements that are naturally inline (e.g. span, a)
Otherwise your element won't render correctly in older browsers (e.g. IE7-)

Answer (score 0):

Include the width of the border in the width of the div.

If you want it to appear 300px wide on the screen, make it 298px (+1px for the left border, +1px for the right border = 300px). This is also true for padding.

Read up on the w3 box model versus the IE box model.